# How to add both an image and text to a QLabel

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5, qpixmap, qlabel

I have a QHBoxLayout with a QLabel in it, and I'm trying to get both an icon and window title text in the QLabel. Is that possible? Or even to add the icon directly to the QHBoxLayout, so that is is laying just before the window title text?

Here is my code:

```
class MyBar(QWidget):

   def __init__(self, parent):
       super(MyBar, self).__init__()
       self.parent = parent
       self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
       self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
       self.title = QLabel("Main Window")

   def changetitle(self, msg):
       self.title.setText(msg)
```

Edit:

Here is the code where I used two labels side by side:

```
    self.label3 = QLabel(self)
    self.title = QLabel("Main Window")
    self.pixmap = QPixmap('res/myIcon.ico')
    self.label3.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
    self.label3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.title.setFixedHeight(35)
    self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.label3)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
    self.label3.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: black;
    """)
    self.title.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    """)
```

Comment: Use two labels side-by-side: one with text, one with a pixmap.

Comment: I have done this already but didn't come with the result needed to have the icon just before the text. Also, there is some white gap between both labels with no black bg which ofcourse looks awful. I edited the Question with the code i used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a demo based on your code that should do what you want:

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label3 = QLabel(self)
        self.title = QLabel("Wild Lion's Browser")
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('icon48.png')
        self.label3.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.title.setMinimumHeight(self.pixmap.height())
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label3)
        layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.label3.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: black;
        """)
        self.title.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        """)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addStretch()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 200, 30)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```